# Why doesn't Read::read_to_string() return the string?

Tags: rust, traits, standard-library

In the [`Read` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), many functions/methods take a `buf: &mut XXX` as (one of the) parameter(s) and return `Result<usize>`. For example, [`read_to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) takes `buf: &mut String` as one of the parameters and returns `Result<usize>`.

As I came from many languages, the so-called *modern* ones usually return the string for a `read_string()` function call. The design of the `Read` trait in Rust kind of shocks me because it doesn't **return** the string, but rather **passes it as a parameter** (similar to C or other more primitive languages).

I'm aware the return value (`Result`) is used to indicate whether the read succeeded or not, and it can be passed to `match` expressions. (I've learned Lisp and Go previously, so I'm not questioning this kind of design.)

Why didn't the core developers design this trait as "returning the string together with the error message"?

For example, why not design it like this:

```
fn read(&mut self) -> Result<String> { ... }
```

The `String` also contains the length, so the user can access the length by calling `.len()` when needed. The user can concatenate it to any other `String` if (s)he wishes, but the key point is that there is no need to create / have one before calling this function.

Is there any particular reasons to design this trait like what it is now?

p.s. I'm still learning Rust (by following [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)), and am reading the second edition after reading most of the first edition. Please correct me if the code above contains any errors (especially when dealing with lifetimes).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Result<&'a str>` wouldn't often be a usable return type for this problem, because it implies the `&'a str` is a reference to a part of the struct that is being called on (since you can't return a reference to something created in a function).

Comment: @BHustus Oh, that should be my fault :P (I think I also can't return `str` directly, right?) What about returning `Result<'a String>`? p.s. I'd think returning `Result<String>` incorrect, because the reference doesn't live long enough, right?

Comment: `'a` and other lifetimes are only relevant when you're returning *references*. When returning a `Result<String>`, you're *moving* the String, which means you don't need to worry about how long it lives. Lifetimes are only designed to keep references from pointing at things after they're deleted.

Comment: (In other words, `&'a str` means "a reference to a `str` that lives for *at least* the duration `'a`.)

Comment: @BHustus That clarifies a lot. Thank you! I have changed the return type to `Result<String>`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that lifetimes are *descriptive* and not *prescriptive*. You can't define arbitrary lifetimes, you can't make something live longer by giving it a lifetime. And by explicitly denoting lifetimes, what you're usually doing is giving an *assurance* to the compiler, rather than an *instruction* (ex. the reference in the return value cannot outlive the struct this function is being called on). That's something I was hung up on for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC 517 (IO reform)](https://github.com/aturon/rfcs/blob/io-reader-writer/text/0517-io-os-reform.md) states (emphasis mine):

> The `read_to_end` and `read_to_string` methods **now take explicit buffers
>   as input**. This has multiple benefits:
>
> - Performance. When it is known that reading will involve some large
>     number of bytes, the buffer can be preallocated in advance.
> - "Atomicity" concerns. For `read_to_end`, it's possible to use this API
>     to retain data collected so far even when a read fails in the middle.
>     For `read_to_string`, this is not the case, because UTF-8 validity
>     cannot be ensured in such cases; but if intermediate results are
>     wanted, one can use `read_to_end` and convert to a `String` only at the
>     end.

Before Rust 1.0, [`Reader::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/io/trait.Reader.html#method.read_to_string) *did* return a `String`. It was a deliberate decision to move away from that.

A `read_and_create_string` function can be created "on top" of `Read::read_to_string`, but the opposite is not true. Code in the standard library needs to be very flexible.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I wanted :) (Strange, I didn't see any notifications for your answer posted.) By the way, why linking to Aaron Turon's repository instead of the rust-lang repository?

Comment: For those interested: [this section](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0517-io-os-reform.md#read) is where the quotation is obtained from.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know the real reason but there are some advantages:

- You control how the `String` is allocated. You can take it from a pool, reuse it, etc.
- You can read to the same string from multiple `read_to_string` (or similar) calls. There's no need to concatenate strings
- The size of the resulting string (in the case of passing as parameter) does not tell you how many bytes you have read (because the `String` can be non-empty), this is why `usize` is returned in a `Result`

The signature

```
fn read_to_string(&mut self) -> Result<String> { ... }
```

might look more natural if coming from higher level languages but it gives no control over the `String` and its allocation.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's *specifically* so that you can re-use the `String` buffer multiple times.  Functions that *accept* a buffer are always more flexible than those that *return* one.

Comment: For performance reason makes a lot sense, and this is also what I suspect the most :)

Comment: I was wondering, for performance reason, why isn't a String returned since Rust has Return Value Optimization (RVO). But, performance is more about RVO.